# double geom_bar, how to get the values for each bar

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I have a ggplot of countries (X axis) over two different time periods (Y axis), so double bar for each country. 
I would like to see the values of each bar. I used geom_text but I get the values on the same line so they are not in place. How can I use geom_text for this type of plot ?

````
Rcountry %>%
  gather("Type", "Value",-Country) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Country, Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal()+scale_fill_grey()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkslategray4", "darkslategrey"))+
  labs(x="Country", y="Stock of robots per thousands worker in '000")+
  geom_text(aes(label=c(X2010, X2018)), size=3.5)```

Thank you
````

Comment: Friendly reminder that `geom_col()` is shorthand for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding `position = position_dodge(.9)` to `geom_text`, i.e. you have to the positioning used in `geom_bar` to `geom_text` to get the labels right. Using `mtcars` as example data, try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x = factor(cyl), mpg, fill = factor(gear))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_fill_grey() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  labs(x="Country", y="Stock of robots per thousands worker in '000")+
  geom_text(aes(label = mpg), position = position_dodge(.9), size=3.5) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>